# How to give seconds of delay before after Button press

Tags: server, 20.04, raspberrypi

I want a 3 second delay after a condition is satisfied which should not stop any other process.

When I press a button for 3 seconds I want a return value true
(timer should only start after button is pressed) else it must be false. Any suggestions how to do it? Here's what I have tried but is not working

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(3, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)


def button():
    if GPIO.input(3) == GPIO.LOW:
      start_time =time.time()
      if (time.time() - start_time) >= 5:
        return True
      else:
        return False
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: ubuntu server 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
def button():
    global start_time, end_time
    if GPIO.input(3) == GPIO.HIGH:
        start_time = time.time()
        return False
    if GPIO.input(3) == GPIO.LOW:
        end_time = time.time()
        if (end_time - start_time) >= 3:
            return True    
        else:
            return False
```